# Why does this text look "less bold" in OS X 10.5 compared to 10.7?

Tags: macos, fonts

I built a very simple application with nothing but a single NSTextView in it in xcode / interface builder. I've done nothing to the text view other than change the font face to "Arial" and increase the font size. However, it looks a lot less bold on OS X 10.5 than it does on 10.7. What's going on here?

[image: 10.5 in the top window, 10.7 in the bottom window]

(10.5 in the top window, 10.7 in the bottom window)

I've tested with Helvetica and got the same results, so it's not something to do with this specific font.

Comment: Apple has changed the font anti-aliasing algorithm used in every major release of OS X. Plus, while the system settings may be set to one option, the system may override that option based on the screen connected.

Comment: Should you do anything to compensate for this, or just accept that it'll look different on different OS's and leave it at that? I'd like our app to be consistent across different versions, but if Apple keeps changing stuff obviously that's not going to happen without adjustments.

Answer (score 1):

If you enlarge that image enough, you'll see color fringing on the 10.7 sample. This indicates that the text was rendered with [subpixel antialiasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering), more specifically, using a RGB subpixel ordering. The 10.5 sample uses grayscale antialiasing. While it is generally a good idea to use subpixel rendering, it can look bad on low-resolution screens or CRTs, and it can't be used in a multi-monitor setup where there is more than one subpixel arrangement to contend with. This means that some users will have subpixel rendering enabled for their system, and some won't. Don't try to circumvent that setting in any way, either by overriding the system preference for font smoothing, or by pre-rendering the text into an image. Users are far more likely to notice the one app whose text looks wrong on their system than they are to notice the difference in rendering between two different machines.